# Line bundle defined by exceptional divisor; $\mathcal O(E) = \pi^*\mathcal O(-1)$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, blowup

In Huybrechts book (Cor 2.5.6), it is shown:

Let $X=\mathbb C^{n}$ and $\hat X$ its blow-up at $0$. Then locally $\mathcal O(E) = \pi^*\mathcal O(-1)$, where $\pi: \hat X \to \mathbb P^{n-1}$.

I have trouble understanding the proof:

[image: Huybrechts p.101]

1. Its clear, that $\bigcup_{(\ell,z)\in \hat X} \ell$ is a line
   bundle. But why is it isomorphic to $\mathcal O(E)$?
2. Why does the section $t(\ell,z)=((\ell,z),z)$ vanish with
   multiplicity $1$?
3. Why does 2. imply $\mathcal O(E) = \pi^*\mathcal O(-1)$?

I think 2. is simply because the function $z$ vanishes with multiplicity $1$ at $0$, but for the rest I have no clue.

Comment: How is the line bundle $\mathscr O(E)$ on $\hat{\Bbb C}{}^n\subset\Bbb C^n\times \Bbb P^{n-1}$ given by transition functions relative to the usual open cover of $\Bbb P^{n-1}$? Doesn't Huybrechts do this explicitly?